# ARM gcc linker error

Tags: sdk, компоновщик

Потребовалось перенести проект с компьютера( был написан в QT) на платформу Xilinx. Компиляцию прошел успешно, но вот линкер у SDK загнулся. Непонятный мне баг. Линкер при создания файлов .о  стал удалять буквы из названия вайлов .с . Как бы я не менял названия файла, линкер удаляет вторую букву и кричит No such file or directory. Даже если меняю название всего с одной буквой, линкер стирает точку(та, что перед с).
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой? 
Внизу добавил принтскрин экрана.
Заранее благодарю.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Стоит проверить makefile, а так же в настройках компилятора какие директории он обходит при компиляции проекта и добавить необходимые в случае их отсутствия там.